# Creating QR Code with Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9

Has anyone gotten the "Open Source QR Code Library" to work with ColdFusion? I need to generate QR Codes in ColdFusion.

I also found [this tutorial](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2009/11/seeing-stripes-experiment-with-zxing.html) on how to generate it using [Zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

But the tutorial is not clear on how to configure the files, e.g. what needs to be in which dir...

Any help and alternatives are welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Zxing uses two (2) jars: `core.jar` and `javase.jar`. The easiest way to install them is to place both jars anywhere in the CF classpath (example: C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\web-inf\lib). Then restart the CF server. That is it.

Note: You can either compile the zxing jars yourself or download a slightly older version from this handy entry on [blog.getRailo.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20121015221510/http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/barcode-generation-with-railo)) **Update:** The *barcode_samples.zip* file does contain sample CF code. But it is for Railo only. Adobe CF does not support the [extra parameters for createObject("java")](http://web.archive.org/web/20160420114900/http://blog.getrailo.com/post.cfm/railo-tip-createobject-java). To use the code in Adobe CF, you need to remove the extra parameters.

```
<!--- Railo syntax --->
<cfset object = createObject('java','path.to.classtoinvoke','/path/to/jar/file/on/system')>
<!--- Adobe CF --->
<cfset object = createObject('java','path.to.classtoinvoke')>
```

If you do not have access to the classpath, you can use the [JavaLoader.cfc](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) to load the two (2) zxing jars instead. Just download the project. It includes some pretty good examples on installation and usage. But if you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I pasted the two files in web-ini\lib and this is what I get when I run the Zxing's index.cfm ERROR: Unable to generate barcode The java object type is unknown for the CreateObject function. Any Ideas?

Comment: @n_kips - The `code` samples are for Railo only. If you are running ACF you need to make some adjustments. Please see my updated comments above.

Comment: @marc esher the code was the un-tempered barcode_samples.zip & Leigh got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially wrap the google API.

Here is the core of the code:

```
<cfhttp method="Get" url="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=#url.text#" getAsBinary = "yes">
```

[Click here to see my blog post for further detail](http://rich-blog.blogspot.com/search?q=qr)

Answer (score 1):

I created a ColdFusion / jQuery QR code generator on my web site. Basically, you just send the info you want to convert in a URL string to Google. They create and host the image.

You can check it out on my site at http://www.EvikJames.com/?StackOverflow It's in the jQuery examples section, "Ajax QR Code Generator"

You can use the code below to see how I did it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#TextBox").keyup(updateImage);
$("#ImageSize").change(updateImage);

function updateImage() {
    var Message = $(this).attr("value");
    var ImageSize = $("#ImageSize").attr("value");
    $("#ResultImage").animate({ height: ImageSize, width: ImageSize}, 500);
    ImageSize = ImageSize + 'x' + ImageSize;
    MyURL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=" + ImageSize +  "&cht=qr&chl=" + Message;
    $("#ResultImage").attr("src", MyURL);
}

});
```

Comment: +1 Yep. Google charts provides a simple interface to the zxing library. It can be a nice alternative for applications that do not need to keep the processing internal only.

Comment: An you benefit from Google covering the bandwidth